# In Magento2 what is <script type="text/x-magento-init">?

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento2, frontend, knockoutjs

I am new to Magento2 and our organisation has just get the EE licence. I have installed it on my local machine and the default template spits out the following mixed in with HMTL:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "customer": {
                    "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And calls like

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
"*": {
    "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
        "components": {
                "messages": {
                    "component": "Magento_Theme/js/view/messages"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Is this to do with `KnockoutJS` or `RequireJS`? What are these calls and what is this new script tag `<script type="text/x-magento-init">`

Comment: Some docs added presumably after this question was posted: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html

Answer (score 37, accepted):

## General usage of "script type"

When using `<script type="....">` the browser interprets only what it knows (like `text/javascript` for example).
Anything else is ignored.
Basically using a custom type you are adding information to the page without displaying it and without the browser interpreting it and you can later use that information as you want.

## How Magento uses this

Magento uses these sections after the page loads.
The code that uses them is located in [`lib/web/mage/apply/scripts.js`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2c311924e6c8f8ae5ddec1d665fa4c7c9ecf4459/lib/web/mage/apply/scripts.js).
I don't understand completely what the file mentioned above does, but there is a comment inside the file that states this:

```
/**
 * Parses 'script' tags with a custom type attribute and moves it's data
 * to a 'data-mage-init' attribute of an element found by provided selector.
 * Note: All found script nodes will be removed from DOM.
 *
 * @returns {Array} An array of components not assigned to the specific element.
 *
 * @example Sample declaration.
 *      <script type="text/x-magento-init">
 *          {
 *              "body": {
 *                  "path/to/component": {"foo": "bar"}
 *              }
 *          }
 *      </script>
 *
 * @example Providing data without selector.
 *      {
 *          "*": {
 *              "path/to/component": {"bar": "baz"}
 *          }
 *      }
 */
```

## Conclusion / Speculation

I speculate that this is a way to set different js behaviour to different elements in the page without the need to rewrite the template that contains the elements.
You only need to add a `<script type="text/x-magento-init">` in one of your templates, include your template in the page and magento "auto-magically" moves the behavior to the right element.

Comment: I tried removing this script in `app/design/frontend/package/template/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml` but no luck. Any advice on removing default behaviors such as product magnifier and/or product gallery (fotorama to be precise)?

Comment: i got a warning  Missing JS component initialization. Use \"x-magento-init\" or \"x-magento-template\".   when i am use <script>tag in phtml file how to solve it.

Comment: guys, is there any real time example for how can i use this passing parameter in data-mage-init? and how it will return result ?

Comment: I can't find any useful examples. Why should we use this?

Comment: what do you consider an useful example? There are 2 examples in the question. You can also look in the source of any frontend page. But if you want a real life example, here goes: Let's say you want to make the upsells list a carousel. You can do that just by adding a template file to the page that contains only the `text/x-magento-init` script that makes the element containing the upsells a carousel. You don't need to modify the upsells template to do that.

Answer (score 11):

In Addition,

**vendor\magento\magento2-base\lib\web\mage\apply\scripts.js**

```
var scriptSelector = 'script[type="text/x-magento-init"]',
        dataAttr = 'data-mage-init',
        virtuals = [];
```

By using below guides

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html

Standard Syntax Is

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    // components initialized on the element defined by selector
    "<element_selector>": {
        "<js_component1>": ...,
        "<js_component2>": ...
    },
    // components initialized without binding to an element
    "*": {
        "<js_component3>": ...
    }
}
</script>
```

By referring

http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_javascript_init_scripts

http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_introducing_ui_components

Magento itself often uses the `x-magento-init` method to invoke a RequireJS module as a program. However, the real power of `x-magento-init` is the ability to create a Magento Javascript Component.

Magento Javascript Components are RequireJS modules that return a function.

Magento encounters a `text/x-magento-init` script tag with an * attribute, it will

1] Initialize the specified RequireJS module (Magento_Ui/js/core/app)

2] Call the function returned by that module, passing in the data object

Hope it helps