# How to pass phtml variable in js file in magento2

Tags: magento2, frontend, jquery, requirejs

This is my phtml file ....

```
    <?php 
$currentCategory = $block->getCurrentCategory();

//echo $currentCategory;
?>
```

I want to set $currentCategory value in js file and display in alert ...How to set it in js file?

Comment: I am not perfectly understanding that answer... If you have answer then please post it...

Comment: You can also refer to this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89187/in-magento2-what-is-script-type-text-x-magento-init

Comment: OR this link - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100787/how-to-pass-variable-to-external-js-in-magento-2

Comment: Or this link if you want more details  - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103861/how-to-use-knockout-js-within-magento-2/103889#103889

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simple use echo in js for print or pass php variables

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 

    var yourvariable = <?php echo $currentCategory; ?>

    alert(yourvariable);

 });
```

If you have diffrent file for phtml and js you can try this

Create input hidden field within you php file like this

```
<input type="hidden" id="myPhpValue" value="<?php echo $myPhpValue ?>" />
```

in your javascript file:

```
var myPhpValue = $("#myPhpValue").val();

//From here you can the whaterver you like with you js Value
if(myPhpValue != ''){
    //Do something here
}
```

Comment: phtml and js file both are different....js code is not used in phtml file... it is separate file..

Comment: Refer my updated answer. if you have diffrent file for phtm and js

Comment: Cool.....It's working for me... Thanks @Prince Patel :)

Comment: @RohanHapani Although this will work it is not following best practices.

Comment: I'm currently writing one, hopefully I have time to finish it.

Comment: @RohanHapani - I can't answer on here as it's on hold, but this is the method I would use - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100787/how-to-pass-variable-to-external-js-in-magento-2

Answer (score 4):

Pass with Div id you will get the value in js file.

Try below code :

Your phtml file should be :

```
<?php 
$currentCategory = $block->getCurrentCategory();
?>
<?php if(isset($currentCategory) && $currentCategory !== "")
      {
?>
<div id="currentCategory"><?php $currentCategory ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

**Your js file should be :**

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 

    var categoryvalue = $("#currentCategory").val();
    alert(categoryvalue);

 });
```

Comment: Happy To help !!! keep helping :)