# How to get values passed from phtml in js magento 2?

Tags: javascript, magento2.2.6

I have passed two variables in my phtml to js file as below

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            ".slider-gallery": {
                "slickSlider": {
                    "autoplay": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getConfigData('autoplay'); ?>,
                    "autoplay_speed":  <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getConfigData('autoplay_speed'); ?>
                }
            }
        }

        </script>
```

My js file is

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'slick'
], function ($) {

    $(document).ready(function () {
 var slickConfig = {
            autoplay: true,
            infinite: true,
            arrows: true,
            dots: true,
            draggable: false,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplaySpeed: 1000,
        };
        $('.slider-gallery').slick(slickConfig);

    });
});
```

How to get values of these variables in my js file?

Comment: get reference from [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/173120)

Comment: Can you please post getConfigData() function code here?

Comment: public function getConfigData($fieldName)
    {
        $configValue = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'slider/slider_js_config/' . $fieldName, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        return $this->_jsonHelper->jsonEncode($configValue);
    }

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: Yes. I tried. Its working !!!! Thank you..

Comment: Please accept answer. So, it will helpful for other developer also. Happy to help !! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple example of passing data from `phtml` template to your `js` using `js-component`.

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            myjscomponent: 'Anshu_Custom/js/customjs'
        }
    }
};
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/view/frontend/templates/myTemplate.phtml**

```
<?php
$yourCustomValue = 'My Custom Data';
?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "myjscomponent": {
            "customData": <?= $yourCustomValue ?>
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/view/frontend/web/js/customjs.js**

```
define([], function(){
    'use strict';

    return function(config, element){
        var myData = config.customData;
        console.log(myData);
    }
});
```

You can modify the code according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this below code in your js :

Modify this below code in your phtml file :

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    ".slider-gallery": {
        "slickSlider": {
            "autoplay": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getConfigData('autoplay'); ?>,
            "autoplay_speed":  <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getConfigData('autoplay_speed'); ?>
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Now, you can get value using this below way :

```
console.log(this.autoplay);
console.log(this.autoplay_speed);
```

Comment: No. It is showing undefined...

Answer (score 0):

In your .phtml file,

```
....
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('Namespace\Module\Helper\Data');
$zoomType = $_helper->getZoomType(); ?>
.....
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
         "quickView": {
              "zoomType": "<?= __($zoomType) ?>"
         }
    }
}
</script>
```

And Obtain **zoomType** is your JS like,

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function ($, _, modal) {
"use strict";

return function (config) {
    console.log(config.zoomType); //Checked passed variable here
    if (config.zoomType == 'hover') {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.fotorama__stage').live('mouseleave', function() {
                $('.magnify-lens').addClass('magnify-hidden');
                $('.magnifier-preview').addClass('magnify-hidden');
            });
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var documentPadding = 25;
        var firstAttempt = true;
        ................
        ................
        ................
    });
};
});
```