# Is there any other way to call data-mage-init?

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, requirejs

On AJAX I want to display the **Buy Now** button. For that, I created one variable

```
 var buy_now_button = '<span title="<?php echo __('Buy Now') ?>" id="buy-now" class="action buynow primary" data-mage-init='{ "Test_Detail/js/buy-now": { "form": "#product_addtocart_form"  }}'><span><?php echo __('Buy Now') ?></span></span>';
```

Because of data-mage-init, the function is not working.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: @BenCrook function does not get called

Comment: @BenCrook Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the single quote needs escaping, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134910/how-to-escape-a-single-quote-in-javascript) you can't simply use `\` to escape the quote either (I'd still give it a try if I was you).

You can use `&apos;` to escape it though, whilst it is not very easy to read what is happening it may solve the problem for you.

**Cleaner Method**

The cleanest way to do this would be to use the `x-magento-init` method, and then you can pass the PHP through to the JS file.

Usage for that method is along these lines:

**PHTML**

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "yourJsAliasOrPathHere": {
                "buyNowButton": "<?php echo ... ?>"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**JS**

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function(config) {
        alert(config.buyNowButton);
    }
});
```

Comment: <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Test_Detail/js/buy-now"": {
                "#buy-now": "<?php echo ... ?>"
            }
        }
    }
</script>

Comment: I have tried above, can u pls explain little more briefly

Comment: You'll need to replace `...` with whatever you want to echo, and escape the quotes in there to. What this does is pass the PHP through to the JS file. I don't have time to explain in detail sorry, the below links should help though. If not then try the method you did before and just escape the quotes. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html and https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89187/in-magento2-what-is-script-type-text-x-magento-init are the links.